# convert string in an array of objects

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I have two different classes: Employee and Customer. Each have two properties in common: Name and Address. Is there a way convert the string directly into an array of objects without using the List<>?

```
    private static List<Employee> NewMethod1(string strArr)
    {
        List<Employee> lst = new List<Employee>();
        if (strArr !=null)
        {
            strArr.Split(',').ToList().ForEach(x => lst.Add(new Employee() { Name = x }));
        }
        return lst.ToArray();
    }
```

or make this line of code generic enough so I can use it inline code?

```
strArr.Split(',').ToList().ForEach(x => lst.Add(new Employee() { Name = x }));
```

Comment: `strArr.Split(',').Select(x => new Employee() {...}).ToList()`?

Comment: wow!! great!! This was really helpful.

Comment: @canton7 if you post it as an answer, I will accept it, otherwise I will accept  4lexKislitsyn's answer. You were first and I would like to give the honor to you first.

Comment: @4lex's answer is perfectly good: accept that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @canton7 said in comments you can use Linq:

```cs
strArr?.Split(',').Select(x => new Employee() {...}).ToList() ?? new List<Employee>()
```